# How to compare modifiers with python?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I'm writing a quick 'n dirty script to create a render-visibility based stop motion animation. In order to optimize things, I'd like to merge objects which have the same modifier configurations.

Unfortunately, I haven't found simple/clean way to check if two objects' modifiers are identical (or mostly identical; if the only way to do it is by comparing each setting of each modifier, I only care about settings which apply to the render).

How can modifiers be compared?

Comment: Could you elaborate with a couple of modifiers and their assoc. render props that need to be equal?

Comment: @batFINGER Well, I was hoping for a general solution.. But I suppose I could live with only merging objects which only have mirror and/or subsurf modifiers, with the same render settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function that returns True if all the properties of mod1 match mod2

```
def mod_equality(mod1, mod2, ignore=["name"]):
    return all(getattr(mod1, prop, True)
             == getattr(mod2, prop, False)
             for prop in mod1.bl_rna.properties.keys()
             if prop not in ignore)
```

Edit: added an ignore list.

Simple test in console, Cube with Subsurf modifier and copied.

```
>>> m1
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].modifiers["Subsurf"]

>>> m2
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers["Subsurf"]

>>> m1 == m2
False

>>> def mod_equality(mod1, mod2):
...     return all(getattr(mod1, prop, True)
...              == getattr(mod2, prop, False)
...              for prop in mod1.bl_rna.properties.keys())
...              
>>> mod_equality(m1, m2)
True
```

A method to see if one object has same modifiers, all with same settings and in same order as another object

```
def same_modifier_stack_ordered(obj1, obj2):
    return all(mod_equality(m, obj2.modifiers[i])
                for i,m in enumerate(obj1.modifiers))
```

Comment: I think the square brackets of the list comprehension should be removed. The `all()` function will then treat the expression as a generator and execute faster in most cases.

Comment: Agreed. Been using  that way for some time, thought for longer than Jan '17 / Thanks for the heads up. Feel free to edit in such changes.